# Can American Express Safekey be loaded in an iframe?

Tags: iframe, payment, 3ds

I've designed an interface for 3DS payments with Verified by Visa and Mastercard Securecode. They both can be loaded in an iframe with very similar width and height.

I was wondering if the same can be done for American Express Safekey. I've been looking for documentation (which was really easy to find both for Verified by Visa and Mastercard Securecode), but I didn't find anything useful.

Thanks for your help.